# JQuery remove class from list of items one by one with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of divs called .item, and I want to fade them in one at a time with a 100ms delay in between each one showing. I'm using tailwind so I want to do this by remove the .opacity-0 class to tie in with the rest of my animations. However they always remove the opacity-0 class at the same time and I've tried a .each() selector in jquery but it didnt work.

Here is a barebones JS Fiddle of what I've got so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/oxv785k9/

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="item opacity-0">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <p>This is the content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item opacity-0">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <p>This is the content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document)
    .ready(function () {

        setInterval(function () {

        $('.item').delay(1000).removeClass("opacity-0")

        }, 500);

    })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` along with `.each`. Since you want to add a delay , you need to change the `timming`. So you can use `i` for `.each` as this will change every time and multiply that with a constant

```js
$(document)
  .ready(function() {
    $('.item').each(function(i, v) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(v).removeClass("opacity-0")
      }, i * 2000)
    })



  })
```

```css
.opacity-0 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item opacity-0">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <p>This is the content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item opacity-0">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <p>This is the content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```